# Oxidation of alkyl side chain of a benzene ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

We do know that the side alkyl chain of benzene ring is oxidized by hot KMnO4 to benzoic acids. But how exactly it happens. I couldn't get a proper mechanism for this reaction.
Please help me out[image: How does this happen]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33735/oxidation-of-alkyl-side-chain-using-kmno4

Comment: Oh...I hadn't noticed that this question has already been put up....thank you for that....