# Does an aryl compound with any functional group attached to it, undergo benzylic oxidation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

[image]>[image]

If you look at this compound, only the benzylic carbon on the top has a hydrogen attached to it, so how do we oxidize only the top part without touching the lower one (not sure if this product is right), and what happens to the $\ce{-CH2}$ in the middle?

Also, does benzylic oxidation with $\ce{KMnO4}$ happen only with alkyl chains (R)? What if it had a carbonyl instead (a ketone let's say) or any other organic functional group attached to a benzene ring, what would happen to it? For example, Molecule Y here:

> [image]

Why did it get oxidized to phthalic acid if the lower benzylic carbon doesn't have any hydrogen atoms attached to it?

Comment: Would you like to check [this out](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33735/83758), also a duplicate of a [previously answered question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/79/83758). Also would you mind editing the pictures you've posted to make them more clear?

Comment: @SirArthur7 Thanks, honestly Im not that satisfied with the answers on the other questions, I updated the picture, and it still is not clear what happens if what attached to benzene group is cyclic with 1 carbon without benzylic hydrogens  like the second picture or contains a carbonyl like the picture i added first clearer

Comment: " The abstraction of a benzylic hydrogen atom is consistent with the fact that arenes with no benzylic hydrogens, such as tert-butylbenzene, do not get oxidised. " 
Then what about my examples? When 1 side has no benzylic hydrogens in the cycle and the other does, logically one side will turn into COOH, what about the other? like the second picture.

Comment: Yes sure, your question isn't a duplicate and IMHO the 1st link I gave you wasn't either. The answered question is largely general and there hasn't been much of discussions targeted at specific functional groups. On a different note, can you cite your image sources? It's quite helpful for others to analyse the issue accordingly. As for the post, let's hope someone answers it well :)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thank you but this link has already been given to me and it did not answer my question. (Picture 2)