# Action of hot alkaline KMnO4 on tert butyl benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

[image]

Side chain oxidation of aryl alkanes takes place if there is at least one alpha hydrogen present by all accounts I presumed that there would be no reaction. However the answer given was trimethyl acetic acid. Is the answer key wrong?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/86/51553

Comment: Permanganate oxidises double bonds, even those in aromatic systems if you use forcing conditions.

Comment: My teacher has taught me same rxn. but acc. to him it happens only in acidic conditions not in basic medium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar reaction with chromium oxide in alkaline solution has been documented.

[image]

The acidic chromium oxide serves the same role as alkaline KMnO4 i.e a strong oxidizing agent. As pointed out by @Waylander in the comments permanganate oxidizes double bonds even in aromatic compounds.

**Reference:**
$\large{•}$ [Chromium Oxidations in Organic Chemistry; By G. Cainelli, G. Cardillo](https://books.google.co.in/books?dq=tert-butylbenzene+drastic+oxidation&hl=en&id=bdTzCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOr9WTgaPYAhXJqI8KHRZnCBcQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=tert-butylbenzene%20drastic%20oxidation&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

For reaction  with $\ce{KMnO4}$, the given compound must have a carbon atom attached directly to the ring and that carbon atom must have at least one hydrogen atom.
But in case of *tert*-butylbenzene this condition isn't  followed and hence is a special case.
The final product obtained on reaction of *tert*-butylbenzene with $\ce{KMnO4}$ is Pivalic acid $\ce{(CH3)3CCOOH}$
(Common name: Dimethylpropanoic acid).

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, kmno4 will not oxidise tertiary butyl benzene. However, under drastic conditions, oxidative cleavage of bonds occur and a mixture of acetic acid and trimethyl acetic acid is formed.
Hence the answer is incorrect. They should have mentioned the word 'drastic conditions'.

Comment: What are "drastic conditions?"  If something lives in the hydrocarbon lakes of Titan then liquid water would seem drastic to it.